# build.sbt unable to resolve dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, dependency-resolution

I am facing one issue, where one internal dependency is not getting resolve.
The thing is i am not even adding that particular dependency in my build.sbt file. Still it is getting refered at the time of build process & failing.

I also removed all the possible internal artifacts from build.sbt assuming if it has any transitive dependency.

Please help

i did almost everything - invalidate caches & restart Intellij IDEA.
change the versions of sbtPlugin, using different java versions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to help you, we need more details like the error message you got.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Let's try to localize your issue, whether it's connected with IntelliJ or sbt. Let's temporarily forget about IttelliJ. If you do `sbt clean compile` what is the output? Please show your `build.sbt`.

Comment: What dmytro said is valid to rule out Intellij, you could also try to print the dependency tree with sbt to see if it might be a transitive dependency.